# How to correctly run f2py example from numpy docs?

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I'm having trouble following one of the [examples shown in the numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments) concerning f2py and callback functions.
I performed the exact same steps as in the first example (i.e. `f2py -c -m callback callback.f`) to wrap `callback.f`:

```
C FILE: CALLBACK.F
      SUBROUTINE FOO(FUN,R)
      EXTERNAL FUN
      INTEGER I
      REAL*8 R
Cf2py intent(out) r
      R = 0D0
      DO I=-5,5
         R = R + FUN(I)
      ENDDO
      END
C END OF FILE CALLBACK.F
```

However, testing the result as in the example, gives me:

```
python
>>> import callback
>>> def f(i): return i*i
... 
>>> print callback.foo(f)
0.0
```

Thus, it returns `0.0` instead of `110.0`, where `0.0` is the initial value of `r` in the Fortran code.
No matter which callback function I use, the result remains the same (unchanged `R`).
I'm using a recent version of `python 3.7` and `numpy` obtained from `conda`.

Can you reproduce that problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is not of much use but I find the same problem, that `foo` returns 0 where 110 is expected. Python 3.7 NumPy 1.16.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by a mismatch between the *expected* and *actual* data types of the external function `FUN`:

- According to the [implicit data typing rules of Fortran](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365fbc/index.html), in `CALLBACK.F`, the `EXTERNAL` function `FUN` has an implicit type `REAL` (since there is no explicit type, or `IMPLICIT NONE` statement).
- However, also looking at the details of the [*second* example in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments), where the F2PY wrapper is created explicitly using `f2py -m callback2 -h callback2.pyf callback.f`, you will note that the result `r` of the external function `fun` is defined as having type `real*8 :: r` (this is also true for the unmodified `callback2.pyf` signature file, so this is the default F2PY behaviour).

In short the problem is that `FOO` expects `FUN` to return a `REAL` result, while from the Python and F2PY wrapper's side the external function is defined to return a `REAL*8` result. A solution is therefore to ensure that `FUN` has the same return type in Fortran and the Python/F2PY wrapper. This can be achieved in several ways, for example by adding a data type specification `REAL*8 FUN` in `CALLBACK.F`:

```
C FILE: CALLBACK.F
      SUBROUTINE FOO(FUN,R)
      REAL*8 FUN
      EXTERNAL FUN
      INTEGER I
      REAL*8 R
Cf2py intent(out) r
      R = 0D0
      DO I=-5,5
         R = R + FUN(I)
      ENDDO
      END
C END OF FILE CALLBACK.F
```

Wrapping this modified `CALLBACK.F` with `python -m numpy.f2py -c -m callback callback.f` as in the example, now gives the desired output:

```
python
>>> import callback
>>> def f(i): return i*i
...
>>> print(callback.foo(f))
110.0
```

For interest sake, the same behaviour that you saw in Python/F2PY can be produced in pure Fortran using two files `prog.f` and `fun.f`:

```
C FILE: PROG.F, including subroutine FOO previously in CALLBACK.F
      PROGRAM MAIN
C     REAL*8 FUN
      EXTERNAL FUN
      REAL*8 R

      R = 0
      PRINT *, "BEFORE: ", R
      CALL FOO(FUN, R)
      PRINT *, "AFTER: ", R

      END

C This is copied from CALLBACK.F 
      SUBROUTINE FOO(FUN,R)
C     REAL*8 FUN
      EXTERNAL FUN
      INTEGER I
      REAL*8 R
Cf2py intent(out) r
      R = 0D0
      DO I=-5,5
         R = R + FUN(I)
      ENDDO
      END
C END OF FILE CALLBACK.F
```

and

```
C FILE: FUN.F containing the function to be called by FOO
      REAL*8 FUNCTION FUN(I)
      INTEGER I
      FUN = I*I
      END
```

Compiled using `gfortran -fcheck=all -Wall -g func.f prog.f`, it gives the following output (in effect the same as your problematic Python example):

```
./a.out
 BEFORE:    0.0000000000000000
 AFTER:    0.0000000000000000
```

Uncommenting both instances of `REAL*8 FUN` in `prog.f` and recompiling solves the problem:

```
./a.out
 BEFORE:    0.0000000000000000
 AFTER:    110.00000000000000
```